# Как сделать фиксированный header

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, прокрутка

Как сделать так, чтобы шапка сайта при прокручивании не исчезала, как на https://burgerking.ru/category/72?

Comment: [How TO - On Scroll Header](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Через position:fixed

```css
.content{
  height: 300vh;
  position: relative;
  padding:70px 0
}
header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  top:0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header>Шапка</header>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать так (как на https://burgerking.ru/category/72), чтобы при прокрутке (был тот же эффект, что и на  https://burgerking.ru/category/72) - 1. чтобы бы было ощущение, что шапка остается поверх содержимого сайта (2. и чтобы было ощущение мерцания шапки)?

Comment: не понимаю о чем вы, мерцание не вижу, а ваша формулировка про 'ощущение' слишком размыта, что имете ввиду, тени, границы, градиенты?

Comment: 1. тени и градиенты. 
2. Сделайте в ответе цвет шапки белый.